# See X-Request-ID in error messages of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, logging

In my environment most PostgreSQL queries are generated from http requests.

In my case every http request has a unique header: X-Request-ID

If there is a error or warning in the PostgreSQL logs, I would like to see the related X-Request-ID to see where the sql query came from.

How to add an extra message like X-Request-ID to log messages of PostgreSQL?

Related: https://serverfault.com/a/797611/90324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres knows nothing about how your application generates the SQL requests that are sent to the database engine. So it also has no idea that there is a HTTP request behind it, let alone the header of such a request.

The information that can be put into a log line is fixed and [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX)

The only "log variable" that you can dynamically change, is the application name. However that requires that your application sets that each time it processes a request.

Before running a SQL query, your application needs to run something like this:

```
set application_name = 'request-42';
```

where `'request-42'` is the request ID you extracted from the HTTP request.

Once you have that, you can add the `%a` to `log_line_prefix` and it will be shown in the log file.

Comment: Nice: `log_line_prefix` with `%a` inserts the application name. This works. Thank you!

Comment: Would this be safe in a concurrent environment though?